# Proving that $f^{-1}$ Is Continuous Via the Topological Definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$I \subset \mathbb R$ is an open interval, and let $f:  I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be strictly increasing and continuous on $I$.  My text first proved that $f^{-1}$ is continuous via the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of continuity.  Now, in the exercise, it is asking us to prove it via the topological definition.  After much trial-and-error, this is what I came up with.

First, we are asked to prove a lemma (and I succeeded in doing so) that if $U \subset I$ is open, then $f(U)$ is open.

Clearly, $f$ is a one-to-one function onto $f(I)$, so $f^{-1}$ exists with dom$f^{-1} = f(I)$.  Now, we claim that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V) = f(V \cap I)$.  By definition, $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V) = \{ \space y \in f(I) : f^{-1}(y) \in V \}$.  Take any $y \in (f^{-1})^{-1}(V)$, and suppose that $x \in I$ is the element such that $f(x) = y$.  Thus, $x \in V \cap I$, entailing that $y = f(x) \in f(V \cap I)$.  Conversely, take any $y \in f(V \cap I)$; suppose that $x \in V \cap I$ is the element such that $f(x) = y$.  Clearly, $y$ is an element of $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V)$.

For continuity, show that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V)$ is open in $f(I)$ for any open $V \subset \mathbb R$.  If $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V) = \emptyset$, then it is open in $f(I)$.  Otherwise, take $y \in (f^{-1})^{-1}(V) = f(V \cap I)$.  By the lemma above, since $V \cap I$ is open, $f(V \cap I)$ is open; there exists a $\delta$ such that $N(y, \delta) \subset f(V \cap I) \subset f(V) \cap f(I)$.  Therefore, we have:

$$N(y, \delta) \cap f(I) = N(y, \delta) \subset f(V \cap I) = (f^{-1})^{-1}(V)$$

Since $y$ is arbitrary, $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V)$ is open in $f(I)$.

As I said, this was all trial-and-error; I did not begin with the intuition that $(f^{-1})^{-1}(V) = f(V \cap I)$.  But in light of the lemma we were asked to prove, it seems to be the right approach.  Please kindly comment, or is there a succincter approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $I$. We have shown that $f(U)$ is open, and since $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)=f(U)$ it now follows that $f^{-1}$ is a continuous map.